# Help with a form being submitted and .htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

I use this rule so all URLs have a trailing slash

```
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

it will convert /about to /about/

The problem is, however, if I submit a form (POST) to /about, when it rewrites to /about/, it loses all the POST info (`$_POST` in PHP is blank)

is there a way to rewrite it for everything except POST'd queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the line before:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
```

before your RewriteRule. (works on Apache 1.3 too)